# operator== order in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, operators

Is there ever any difference when it comes to order with the `operator==`?

I came across an old exam where it says:

> observe that `*it1 == *it2` is not the same as `*it2 == *it1`

`it1` in this case is an iterator of some type `IT1` and `it2` is an iterator of some type `IT2`. `IT1 it1` and `IT2 it2` are taken as parameters to a function, where `IT1` could be the same as `IT2`. Example code:

```
template <typename IT1, typename IT2>
bool f(IT1 it1, IT2 it2) {
    return *it1 == *it2;
}
```

Any thoughts? In my head, order should not affect the outcome of `operator==`, so I'm confused.

Comment: May have confused with assign operator `=`?

Comment: It might make a difference if the == operator is overloaded in such a way that is is no longer commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually operator overloading could produce unexpected results. Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    int operator==(const Bar& bar) { std::cout << "foo == bar\n"; return 0; }
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {}
    int operator==(const Foo& foo) { std::cout << "bar == foo\n"; return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    foo == bar; // prints "foo == bar"
    bar == foo; // prints "bar == foo"

    return 0;
}
```

Here actually two *different* operator== get called.

Comment: How is this behaviour unexpected?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there can be a difference, because a given implementation of `operator==` can be asymmetric.  Generally speaking this is not a very good way to code, but it can happen.  `==` is symmetric for primitive types like `int`, but for user-defined classes anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator tests if the values on both sides of the operator are equal.

How could it possibly matter which value goes on the left and right sides of the operator? That has no bearing on whether or not they are equal.

Of course, you could overload the operator to have some non-standard behavior, in which case it could matter. But that would be a bad approach, and would not make clear which value should go on the left and which value should go on the right side of the operator.